# scripts included in partials dont work as expected in ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I use lodash accross my website and its now telling me that uniqBy is not a function. I thought maybe this was due to me using an older version of the library so I updated it and still had the same issue. I do bring it into the html via ejs `<%- include %>` but when using something like ejs lodash wont work as expected. I try to use `_.uniqBy` to sort an array but unless I specifically insert a lodash script into html it wont work.

```
<%- include ../partials/scripts.ejs%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/accounting/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/accounting/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/accounting/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/accounting/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/accounting/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lodash.js"></script> Works with this -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Returns undefined unless the lodash script tag is uncommented
    console.log(_.uniqBy);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cost/list.js">//Lodash used in here</script>
<%- include ../partials/footer.ejs%>
```

And the scripts partial is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lodash.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cookiebar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/slide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/email.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jspdf.js"></script>
```

In my cost/list.js I use jquery with `document.ready()` before I use lodash so my question is why does this happen? I thought maybe first it was scope but It cant be as I use these files everywhere and never had this issue before. Then I thought maybe it was the loading as the ejs including of partials could load either before or after the page is ready but my js cost/list.js should wait for it to be ready due to the `$(document).ready()`. Im not sure what the issue is and any ideas as to whats happening with the ejs includes would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went through the page a bit more and found out its pdfmake use lodash too but they use an older version(3.x) whereas today im on (4.17.4) this is why as pdfmakes lodash comes last it takes precedence and becomes the global. Hopefully this will help someone in the future. Check your scripts I went through them one by one moving my lodash script after every other script and found it that way